# How to keep different views decoupled with MVVM

Tags: mvvm, decoupling, coupling

My application is designed to load up an XML file and display an error(s) (if any).

The problem I have is how to display both (the XML and Errors) on screen without coupling (my application does currently work).

My application currently looks like (no laughing or comments about me going on a Photoshop\UI course please):

[image]

The brown colour is a different view called XmlView.
The red box is where I want errors to be displayed.

So, the user clicks File->Open, selects the file and the .XML content is displayed in my XmlView (brown) and my error messages are shown in red. This works but, I have a horrible feeling my design is poor as I have totally coupled my MainWindow and XmlView.

The way I have this working is, when the user selects a valid XML file (from File->Open), I create an instance of my XmlView and bind it to my Views property of my MainWindow class. My XmlView takes 1 parameter which is the MainWindow type.

So, within my XmlView, to update my ErrorList, I would write code similar to

```
_mainWindow.ErrorList.Add(//newError)
```

But this now means my XmlView knows about my MainWindow which I thought was undesired.

So, finally, my question! Is my design poor or is this OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider [using an MVVM framework if you are doing MVVM](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/UsingTheMVVMPatternRequiresAFramework.aspx).

It would depend on whose responsibility it was to load the XML, but I would suggest the `XmlViewModel`, not the `MainViewModel`.

In that case the `MainViewModel` should just be a conductor of other view models. In your first case, it would instantiate the `XmlViewModel`, passing the file path and set it as its current view.

The `XmlViewModel` would be responsible for loading and validating the XML. It too could have a child view model which displays the validation errors. It should load the XML asynchronously, with some form of busy notification.

The `MainViewModel` is likely to want to conduct many view models, so if you were going to use a framework such as [Caliburn.Micro](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com), this would be a [conductor type](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens,%20Conductors%20and%20Composition).

Comment: This is a great answer, but when the XmlViewModel validates the XML and encounters an issue, the problem is how to display the 'error' in my MainViewModel with out the coupling I've described. Or is this potentially something one of the frameworks can help with?

Comment: It seems a better design to have this as a child of the XmlViewModel, as won't you be supporting multiple XML files being open at the same time, each with their own error list?

Comment: If you did want the shell (MainViewModel or ShellViewModel) to create this error window/view, then you could use a mediator pattern, such as the one provided by the EventAggregator in Caliburn.Micro. You could also use standard .NET events which the shell subscribes to.

Comment: ... events! I never thought of using that along the MVVM! Ok, this is brilliant. Although I agree, it would appear a better design if the XmlView took care of everything to do with Xml (validation/loading/saving etc). Great answer, sorry I can only give 1x +1